# Why does my react app go blank when I import {db} from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently making an instagram clone and now am on the part where I need to use useEffect in React to Push or Pull data from Firebase Google Database. When I input:

import { db } from './firebase
my react app goes blank and I can not figure out what percisely is wrong but I know its within me trying to import db from firebase.

This is my code is firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';


const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxx"
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage, firebase};
```

And this is my code in App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { db } from './firebase';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      username: "Jonz",
      caption: "SO COOL!",
      imageUrl:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80"
    },
    {
      username:"Sammiez",
      caption:"That is so funny!",
      imageUrl:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvojQij-7EYR5_qyxwZ5ri3NfuiUsLdQQukFcHFoOpVA&s"
    }
  ]);


  // useEffect -> Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    // this is where code runs
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      // every time a new post is added, this code fires
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    })
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">

    <div className="app__header">
      <img
        className="app__headerImage"
        src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/logged_out_wordmark.png/7a252de00b20.png"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>

    <h1> I need to learn more about react</h1>

    {
      posts.map(post => (
        <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>

      ))
    }

    
     {/* Post */}
     {/* Post */}
    </div>
    

  );
}

export default App;
```

I have not tried anything. I believe it is because I don't have the right syntax for firebase v9 , but I don't know the correct way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your console say regarding errors?

Comment: it says this:  Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\menel\Instagram\instagram-clone\src\App.js:1
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

You could try the imports this way according to documentation :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
const storage = getStorage();

export { db, auth, storage};
```

Example for getStorage() from documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference . Check all the create reference tabs for each you're wanting to use